# How to write unit test cases for a component in Jest React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to write a test case for a component. I am new in unit test cases so Can anyone help me in writing unit test case for below component.

Component code is -

```
<TableContainer className={classes.tableContainer}>
      {data.map((item: any, index: number) => (
      <Box component="div" key={index} className={classes.contentBox}>
      <ListItem
        width="100%"
        thickness={"0px"}
        contentHTML={
          <>
          <TestComponent
            userImage={item.userImage}
            dateTime={item.dateTime}
            userName={item.userName}
            productOrderId={item.productOrderId}
            status={item.status}
            userId={item.userId}
            badgeCount={item.badgeCount}
            handleJoinButtonClick={props.handleJoinButtonClick}
          />

          </>
        }
      ></ListItem>
    </Box>
      ))}
    </TableContainer>
```

We have two records in data. I am using Materiaul UI for CSS. How Can I write unit test cases for this component in Jest Enzyme ?

Comment: Have you tried something? If you didn't please go through some enzyme-jest docs. No one is here you teach you everything from scratch. Really sorry to say this. But ask help if you get stuck somewhere. https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html here is a simple example of how to use shallow testing.

Comment: just fyi the fragment around TestComponent is not needed